# Why IsNumber decorator remove decimal point being passed

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

I'm trying to figure out why DTO property that I declared as type number changed if I passed in decimal. E.g passing engine value of 2.0 will converted into 2. How do I keep it as 2.0 instead of 2?

```
export class TestDTO {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNumber()
  engine: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do like this. The scale parameter indicates the number of decimal points.

```
@Column({ type: 'numeric', precision: 10, scale: 1, default: 0 })
engine: number;
```